# PDF- corrupt file

Tags: pdf

Today I went to somebody with a PDF file, I've made it with LibreOffice Writer, but, when he tried to open the file, it said that it was a corrupt file, my PDF.

I've put the file on my usb stick, and from there he opened it.

What can I do to open that file on that pc? I have to say that other files (PDF) can be opened on that pc. My file can't be corrupt because some of my friends can open it.

Thank you.

Comment: No. I didn't emailed him. I went to him, with a USB flashdrive, and he couldn't open it. But he could open other pdf files.

Comment: Which PDF reader does he use? When he clicks on About, what is its version number?

Comment: I don't really know, I don't have accces to that computer and he said to me that he couldn't open it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

His PDF reader could be old, and not able to read up to date formats. However, you could create a PDF in a different way, by opening the LibreOffice Writer file, select Print, and Print to a PDF.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I just want to print a project, I will tell him to upgrade because he can loose clients like this. Thank you again.